# Sonata Admin compile form field from query string

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

In Sonata Admin is it possible to set or precompile a value in a form taking it from the query string?

I have a custom page with a calendar and when I click a date on the calendar I would like to be redirected to the create page of an event where the date is already set from the query string. Something like:

http://localhost:8000/admin/app/event/create?date=2017-07-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the **request service** and a **field marked as `'mapped' => false`** on my form builder:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $dateParameter = $request->query->get('date');
    $date = null;

    if ($dateParameter) {
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $dateParameter);
    }

    if (!$date) {
        $formMapper
            ->add('date', DatePickerType::class)
            ->add('calendarDate', HiddenType::class, array(
                'data' => null,
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
        ;
    } else {
        $formMapper
            ->add('date', DatePickerType::class, array(
                'data' => $date,
                'disabled' => true,
            ))
            ->add('calendarDate', HiddenType::class, array(
                'data' => $date->format('Y-m-d'),
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
        ;
    }

    $formMapper
        // other fields
        ->add('other_field', ModelType::class)
    ;
}
```

Then, on the following method I am updating the entity field:

```
public function prePersist($myEntity)
{
    $this->preUpdate($myEntity);
}

public function preUpdate($myEntity)
{
    $dateString = $this->getForm()->get('calendarDate')->getData();
    if ($dateString) {
        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $dateString);
        if ($date) {
            $myEntity->setDate($date);
        }
    }
}
```

In this way I can use my form with or without the query string parameter `date`:

http://localhost:8000/admin/app/event/24/edit?date=2017-07-01

[image]

And in the HTML I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="s59664a9ea44ce_calendarDate" name="s59664a9ea44ce[calendarDate]" class=" form-control" value="2017-07-01" />
```

**P.S. when someone gives a -1 it should be nice to explain why...**